# performing $lookup on subset of collection

Tags: mongodb

I have this data

```
[
{"_id":0,"a":1,"b":1,"source":1},
{"_id":1,"a":1,"c":4,"source":1},
{"_id":2,"a":2,"d":6,"source":1},
{"_id":3,"a":2,"e":6,"source":1},
{"_id":4,"a":2,"f":6,"source":1},
{"_id":5,"a":3,"d":6,"source":1},
{"_id":6,"a":3,"b":1,"source":1},
{"_id":7,"a":3,"f":6,"source":1},
{"_id":8,"a":3,"qq":3,"source":2},
{"_id":9,"a":3,"fl":6,"source":2}
]
```

I want to return all documents whose `a` field is equal to the `a` field of a document that has a field `b`. Furthermore, all must be from source 1.

The final result should be this:

```
[
{"_id":0,a":1,"b":1,"source":1},
{"_id":1,"a":1,"c":4,"source":1},
{"_id":5,"a":3,"d":6,"source":1},
{"_id":6,"a":3,"b":1,"source":1},
{"_id":7,"a":3,"f":6,"source":1}
]
```

The following query gives me the results I want:

```
myCollection.aggregate([{"$match":{"b":{"$exists":true},"source":1}},
                {"$group":{"_id":null, "a":{"$addToSet":"$a"}}},
                {"$unwind":{"path":"$a"}},
                {"$project":{"_id":false}},
                {"$lookup":
                    {"from": "myCollection",
                     "localField":"a",
                     "foreignField":"a",
                     "as":"results"}},
                {"$project":{"a":false}},
                {"$unwind":{"path":"$results"}},
                {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$results"}},
                {"$match":{"source":1}}
                ])
```

However, having to add that last `{"$match":{"source":1}}` statement got me thinking that for large sets of data the `$lookup` statement is going to produce a lot of unwanted results that will then be filtered out by my last `$match` statement. Is there any way to prevent their generation by limiting  `$lookup`  to documents from myCollection where source equals 1?

ie replace

```
{"$lookup":
    {"from": "myCollection"
```

with something like

```
{"$lookup":
    {"from": myCollection.match({"source":1})
```

Alternatively, is there a more efficient pipeline I could be using?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter few documents in the pipeline of `$lookup` stage. This will help in to gain some performance and avoid unnecessary results. You can use it like below:

```
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "collection",
    "let": {
      a_: "$a"
    },
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$source",
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$a",
                  "$$a_"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "as": "results"
  }
}
```

Your `$project` stage,

```
{"$project":{"a":false}}
```

is useless actually, you can omit it.